# iOS AVFoundation - is it possible to add text/image into the video via position/motion tracking?

Tags: ios, video, ffmpeg, avfoundation, video-editing

I am aware of how to add text / image overlay into a video on iOS with AVFoundation.

1. Is there some way to do this using position/motion tracking of certain objects / areas in the video?
2. What exactly is this type of video editing feature called?

Let's say I have a video of a car moving from left to right. I want to place an image of another car at the position of the original car so that as the car in the video is moving from left to right, my image follows on top of that car. I would also want this to be properly skewed as the car moves from left to right.

Another example would be a video of a monitor. And me placing an image on the screen of that monitor.

Please let me know if I need to explain further.

Other than iOS is there some other library which is able to do this? Like ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

What you're broadly looking for is Object Recognition, which is a fairly complex topic in it's own right and part of the field of Computer Vision.

AVFoundation includes support for Face Detection and does a fairly reasonable job of it https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avmetadatafaceobject but that's about it.

To do what you're trying to do, I'd start with OpenCV (which includes support for iOS) and investigate from there http://opencv.org/

You're not going to find a literal "find me a car" API, what you will find is lots of different algorithms which are implemented that allow you to train them and detect the objects they are trained for.  One potential algorithm is using Haar Cascades.  There's more detail on working with those and training your own classifier here https://github.com/andrewssobral/vehicle_detection_haarcascades

Comment: thank you for your reply. My actual goal is much simpler. I don't want to actually detect objects OR find objects/car. Let's say that I already have the exact position (coordinates) in the video where I want to place something. And this only needs to be done on a specific single video I have. The area I am selecting is also pretty "white"/good contrast as compared to the rest of the stuff around it. Will this make things easier? I am looking into the links you attached, thanks!

Comment: that opencv looks VERY promising! This video shows how it can help me https://youtu.be/bSeFrPrqZ2A?t=5m38s

Comment: so let's say I can use opencv to detect the "white" area in my video which I am trying to replace with my own image. How would I go about actually doing the "replacement" and export that video? Like does AVFoundation have some way to specify the positions/coordinates in the video which needs to be replaced? Or will I need to go through each frame of the video, do the replacement, then combine them to create a new video? Also any way to make my replacement image "3D' like it follows the angles as in the video? All this seems pretty similar to how the snapchat face filters work.

Comment: Bear in mind that SnapChat Face Filters are a proprietary, patented tech they bought, not something you can just "use of the shelf", yes, the basic concept is easy to describe, the technical implementation is much harder! As far as animating something over a specific area, you have two options - you can use either a CAAnimationLayer, perhaps with something like a BezierPath, or yes, frame by frame if you need more complex solutions.  If you have a specific color that you're replacing, you might try looking at a Chroma Key.